# Stack Overflow freezes when opening specific post on the desktop site

Tags: bug, status-completed, specific-question, syntax-highlighting

Not sure if this is universal but on my desktop, laptop, and phone desktop site when opening [BigInt inconsistencies in PowerShell and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62974138/bigint-inconsistencies-in-powershell-and-c-sharp/62974529) I get stuck loading into the question and eventually getting a "page responsive error" on Chrome, Brave, Brave Beta, Brave Dev, Mozilla Firefox, and Edge. Can't click anything or interact with any of the elements. Sometimes more things load than other times but overall the website just breaks.

Not sure if this is the case for everyone but doesn't work for me

Comment: I think the markdown parser breaks on that answer

Comment: Is there any way I can open it then?

Comment: @rene I thought markdown was parsed server side and then the converted markup was sent to users

Comment: @Nick good point, how about Hightight.js being the culprit

Comment: That I find more likely

Comment: I see highlight js bark about powershell not being found

Comment: @rene Really? A lot of my other answers all have powershell and it looks like the syntax highlighting looks fine then. However you can't get highlighting if you tag ps1 rather than powershell. It's also listed on their website

Comment: It hangs a bit for me but loads eventually, with a console full of warning messages (Firefox on latest macOS). "Could not find the language 'powershell', did you forget to load/include a language module?"

Comment: Yeah, it's 100% syntax highlighting, blocking the highlighter using `||cdn.sstatic.net/Js/highlightjs-loader.en.js` as a uBlock filter resolves the issue

Comment: Yeah I have the same conclusion as @Nick I've pinged Josh Goebel

Comment: Code blocks with tens of thousands of "9" characters all on one line are not a great idea.  Tried to fix the worst case of them, didn't really work.

Comment: @HansPassant [Highlight.js maintainer here] If someone can reproduce this bug with the latest Highlight.js release (10.6) please file an issue on our GitHub and I'll take a quick look.  I was pretty sure we'd nailed all the runaway regex issues pretty well.  But with "tens of thousands" it sounds like it may be hitting a polynomial issue rather than exponential, which is much harder to fully guard against.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fun!

Looks like it was falling over while trying to apply syntax highlighting. We defaulted highlighting for the [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) tag to `lang-bsh`, probably because that was a good idea when we were using Prettify.

We currently [aren't including the actual Powershell grammar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) with highlight.js either, but I flipped the default styling associated with the tag to "default". It looks reasonable to my untrained eye, and as a bonus, fixes that specific page.

Comment: Wil PowerShell formatting ever be implemented? It is on the highlight.js website as well.

Comment: @NekoMusume Hopefully. There are no immediate plans to expand the list of languages we include, but we know we can definitely make the system smarter and better. Unfortunately, finding the time to do so is a challenge at the moment.